# How do I know what caused the extent of my axMapControl to be updated?

Tags: arcgis-10.3

I have an [axMapControl](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000050000000) in a WinForms application. According to the [ArcGIS documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OnExtentUpdated_Event/00160000025w000000/),

> [The]`OnExtentUpdated` [event] is triggered whenever the `IMapControl2::Extent`
>   property is changed. Setting the extent explicitly, zooming, panning
>   or using the `IMapControl2::CenterAt` method will change the extent.

But how can I know (programmatically) inside the [event handler](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OnExtentUpdated_Event/00160000025w000000/) that it was zooming or panning that caused the extent to change? I am looking for some C# code which would enable me to know that the extent change was caused by one of those two things.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of this event handler (sizeChanged) checks whether the size of the extent is changed.

```
IMapControlEvents2.OnExtentUpdated (
  IDisplayTransformation displayTransformation,
  bool sizeChanged,
  IEnvelope newEnvelope
);
```

if the sizeChanged is true, then a zoom is happened, else its a pan!

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to know in the event handler that the extent change was caused by neither the zoom nor the pan? For example if the extent was explicitly set in code?

Comment: I don't think that is possible with this event listener. In fact, when a zoom/pan happens, in the code behind the extent is changed. So either ways the extent is changed within the code.

Comment: To distinct between users zoom/pan and extent change using coding, you should check for the active tool in the event listener. If the active tool is pan/zoom then it is a pan and zoom.

Comment: Sounds good - do you think you could provide a code example in your answer to make it really clear?